# How can I efficiently join a dataframe in spark with a directory of small files?

Tags: python, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, join

I have a dataframe (`df1`) with the columns `id, date, type`. I need to join it with a file `/descriptions/{id}.txt`. The result of the join should be a dataframe `id, date, type, description` for all entries in (`df1`) .

The goal is to use this preprocessed dataframe for futher analysis so I don't have to deal with the small files anymore.

Worth noting: There are a lot more small description files than I need (x1000) so I think some kind of "lazy join" would be more efficient than reading all of the small files upfront and join then.

How would you build this in Spark? I use scala currently but if you have a python example I think I could work with that as well.

Comment: Would it be possible to rename the files?

Comment: Would be a big change in the production system. There should be a really good reason to do so. What would you rename it to?

Comment: If they were named `descriptions/id={id}`, you could read them directly with `spark.read.csv("descriptions")` ;-)

Comment: and there is no way to declare this path pattern manually (so spark can lazy-load the files)

Comment: I thought about that but I could not find anything... That might be possible though.

Answer (score -1):

**Option 1, reading all the files:**

You could read the descriptions with `wholeTextFiles`. It returns a RDD mapping the file paths to their content, and then join the result with your dataframe.

```scala
val descriptions = sc
    .wholeTextFiles(".../descriptions")
    // We need to extract the id from the file path
    .map{ case (path, desc) => {
        val fileName = path.split("/").last
        val id = "[0-9]+".r.findFirstIn(fileName)
        id.get.toLong -> desc
    }}
    .toDF("id", "description")

val result = df1.join(descriptions, Seq("id"))
```

**Option 2, reading only the files you need**

For that, you could use `binaryFiles`. It creates a RDD that maps each file path to a `DataStream`. Therefore, the files are not read right away. Then you can select all the distinct `id` from `df1`, join them with the RDD and then only read the content of the files you need. The code would look like this:

```scala
val idRDD = df1
    .select("id").distinct
    .rdd.map(_.getAs[Long]("id") -> true)

val descriptions = sc.binaryFiles(".../descriptions")
    // same as before, but the description is not read yet
    .map{ case (path, descFile) => {
        val fileName = path.split("/").last
        val id = "[0-9]+".r.findFirstIn(fileName)
        id.get.toLong -> descFile
    }} // inner join with the ids we are interested in
    .join(idRDD)
    .map{ case(id, (file, _)) => id -> file}
    // reading the files
    .mapValues(file => {
         val reader = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(file.open)
         val desc = reader.getLines.mkString("\n")
         reader.close
         desc
    })
    .toDF("id", "description")

val result = df1.join(descriptions, Seq("id"))
```

Comment: Nice, that could be worth a try. I assume this is also distributed to different nodes. Do I have to / Can I additionally parallelize the reading of the stream? `reader.getLines.mkString("\n")` will have a lot of IO wait time I think.
Who downvoted and why? ...

Comment: I don't know, someone downvoted your question as well :)

Comment: As to the reading of the streams, the files are read in parallel by spark (one at a time per core in fact). This means that each individual file is handled by only one core (so not in parallel) if that was your question. But you were saying that the files were small so that should work well.

Comment: I would say *because* they are so small but many, I would benefit from an additional paralellization per core. (The IO overhead per call is pretty high)

Comment: Yes. binaryFiles already scans the whole directory. Not great but only a few minutes overhead. But reading the small files used less than 1% of cpu and only very little io. I need to further parallelize it. What would you suggest?

Comment: It would use the available cpu and bandwidth resources better because most time is spend in IO wait.

Comment: That's not how it works. Accessing a file has an overhead. Since you have lots of small files, you will pay that overhead regardless of the number of cores...

Comment: Well, this statement is generally wrong in CS [see multitasking]. But maybe unfortunately correct in the spark context.